# CUDA: complex matrix multiplication

Tags: cuda, cublas

I am solving a large number of linear equations with complex numbers and I need to upgrade my solver with CUDA.I wanted to make use of `cublas` so I used `cuComplex` but I don't want the pre-processing or the post processing to depend on CUDA and hence I only want to use `cuComplex` in the solver.I can iterate through my complex arrays and change them to `cuComplex` but I need a faster approach as I am dealing with a huge number of equations.

Comment: What is your question? The storage conventions of `cuComplex` are identical to the complex data types built into C, C++, and Fortran, so there should be no need for conversion. Simply pass a pointer to the array of the native complex type. Note that the storage conventions for complex types in MATLAB are different.

Comment: @njuffa Actually,I didn't know they are identical. Thanks for your answer.